# Changing center of mass on body Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My question is pretty simple yet I cannot find an answer anywhere in documentation or on stack.

I am working on a game in Corona SDK and I have created a physics body that will be thrown across the screen. The physics body is an image. The object is meant to be a projectile and I would like to use the natural physics inherent to Corona to govern how the object reacts to being thrown across the screen. In order to do this it would be ideal for the object's center of mass to be at the nose/point of the object, somewhat like a badminton shuttle.

**The question is: is there a way to set a custom center of mass of a physics body in Corona?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this, so I am posting my solution here so that others may find it.

Corona does not have a method or property that can be used to change the center of mass for a particular object.

The best way to change the center of mass of an object is to create another object with a heavier density than the original, position Object B at the x,y of the desired position for the center of mass, then make object B's density greater than Object A. Then using a weld joint, join the two objects and thereafter apply any linear forces to the center of mass of Object B. Object B will then drag Object A along as it is rigidly attached via the weld joint.